# Who's the artist that drew the art on pages 148 and 220 of the PHB?

Tags: dnd-5e, books, art

Anyone know the name of the artist or artists that drew the art on page 148 and 220 in the Player's Handbook? I know there's a list of artists in the credits, but looking through it, I haven't been able to find that art specifically on any of their online portfolios.

Also, does anyone know if there exist uncropped versions of said art, and where you might find them?

Comment: Good review of the Player's Handbook and lists of artists and their art @ http://boingboing.net/2014/07/21/an-exclusive-look-at-the-new-d.html

Comment: Email Wizards of the Coast and ask.

Answer (score 18):

The art on page 148 is ["Shield bash" by John Stanko](http://stankoillustration.com/shield/).

The art on page 220 is ["Burning Hands", also by John Stanko](http://stankoillustration.com/burning-hands/).

Comment: I went ahead and added links to the site of the artist who you cite, where those illustrations are listed. Still, this answer could be improved by explaining how you found out (especially given how the other answer speculatively disagrees). We do require all answers to be backed up here and we encourage  [edit]ing answers to improve them. :)